# What is the AppleCare agreement's location?

Tags: applecare

I bought my Mac and AppleCare in Oz, but I mainly use my Mac in Hong Kong. When I register my AppleCare, it asks me to fill in the location. What is this about? Which location should I choose? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The AppleCare agreement is bound to the place of purchase. In your case Oz. If you'd like to transfer it, you'll have to call Apple and ask them. In any case, their customer service is exceptional and I doubt they will refuse service even if you're in HK. For registration however, select Oz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pick the location/country you've bought your Apple product.
The AppleCare states clearly you have "care" around the entire world, as they state even abroad is no problem. You don't have to move your product, as it's part of the Care you're paying for.

My iPad came from Canada and I'm using it in the Netherlands. Registered it first as Canada to avoid problems.